# FLutter Video player had error com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoplaybackException:MediaCodecVideoRender error

Tags: flutter

**My full error : Video player had error com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoplaybackException:MediaCodecVideoRender error, index=0,format=Format(1,null,null,video/avc,avc1.64001E,-1,null[1080,1922,29.999998],[-1,-1]),format_supported=NO_EXCEEDS_CAPABILITES**

I am using video player with chewie player for playing video from url but unfortunately i am facing error which i was described.

My all video have extension .mp4 and its work fine without using chewie controller but when i used chewie controller its not work properly.

**Screenshot of Error**

[image]

**Followiong are my code**

```
late VideoPlayerController _controller;
late ChewieController _chewieController;

@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _initializeVideoPlayer();
  }

Future<void> _initializeVideoPlayer() async {
    try {
      _controller = VideoPlayerController.networkUrl(Uri.parse(widget.videoUrl));
      //await _controller.initialize();
      _chewieController = ChewieController(
        videoPlayerController: _controller,
        autoInitialize: true,
        autoPlay: false,
        looping: false,
        showControls: true,
        errorBuilder: (context, errorMessage) {
          return Center(
            child: Text(
              errorMessage,
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            ),
          );
        },
      );
    } catch (error) {
      print('Failed to initialize video player: $error');
    }
  }

@override
  void dispose() {
    _controller?.dispose();
    _chewieController?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/2,
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          _chewieController != null
              ? Chewie(controller: _chewieController)
              : CircularProgressIndicator(),

          Positioned(
              left: 0,
              top: 0,
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 40,
                    child: IconButton(
                      onPressed: () async{
                        print("download tap");
                        setState(() {
                          isShareTap = false;
                        });
                        if(isAdsLoaded == true){
                          await showRewardedAds();
                        }else{
                          _downloadFile(widget.videoUrl);
                          showToastMessage("Download started...");
                        }

                      },
                      icon: Icon(
                        Icons.download,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 40,
                    child: IconButton(
                      onPressed: () async {
                        print("share tap");
                        setState(() {
                          isShareTap = true;
                        });
                        if(isAdsLoaded == true){
                          await showRewardedAds();
                        }else{
                          shareVideo();
                        }
                      },

                      icon: Icon(
                        Icons.share,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```